# PHP session not registering the first time

Tags: php, session, time, set

I am having an issue with the session variables.

I am having a simple signup php page that uses ajax calls to verify username and email address if they already exist. It also has an ajax image uploader that gives a preview of the selected image.

Now this is how I am setting the session variable :-

```
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
session_start();

$_SESSION['avurl'] = $filename;
```

$filename is valid as it is echoed in the above code just after this snippet.

In the page where I need to use this session variable I have this :-

```
session_start();

$av_url = $_SESSION['avurl'];
```

Now the weird thing is that whenever this runs the first time the session variable doesn't have any value. But the second time it works.

How I came to check this is that I created a test.php which just echos $_SESSION['avurl'] and the first time it never shows anything but the second time it does.

What I figured out from this is that once it echoes this session variable it starts working to store the value.

And all that code that I am using to set that variable is edited from just :-

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['avurl'] = $filename;
```

to that as this also didn't work and I thought that this could be a problem with already existing sessions.

Thankyou
Hope this is enough information for solving my problem !!

Comment: Use session_start() only once at top of your coding and session_destroy and session_unset is used to flush session.

Comment: It's still not working after using session_start() once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
session_unset();
```

This code delete Your session... Why You doing this?

Comment: Correct. What's the point in starting a session and then calling session_unset to disable the registration of ANY variable into session scope?

Comment: I am again starting the session after that, and as I said its working all fine the second time and also when I used the normal code

session_start();

$av_url = $_SESSION['avurl'];

This also doesn't works..

Comment: Your sure, that You are starting session before any html code or php output? (on each page)

Comment: In the php file where i need to use this php variable I hav session_start() at top but in the page where it is set it is inside an if statement which checks if the value input by the user is valid.
And the page where the variable is set, that php file is used only to assign values and give response to the page where it redirects after setting the variable..

Comment: Move session_start() to top of each page. It's no matter where You making operation with session variables, just session supposed to be started on top. (and comment all session destroy and unset)

Comment: OK I did as u said and it seems to be working :D...
Thanks a lot
Only one more thing I am curious to know
If a session is already set and if I use this session_start() on this php file where it sets $_SESSION['avurl'] which now has only session_start() and no session_unset and _destroy.
So will this variable always be set and there won't be any conflict with the existing session?
I mean to say that this code will work in all situations now, is'nt it? I have removed the session_destroy session_unset and session_start is now called once.

Comment: This session always be set. There shouldn't be any conflict if You will not use same name for other variables.